# Cannot access phpMyAdmin due to outbound port blocking

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, webserver

I have a remote mySQL table that I use in a few tools, occasionally I need to access the table from inside a particular test site temporarily. The problem is I cannot access phpMyAdmin because an outbound port is blocked at this site.  My phpMyAdmin is accessed through a Plesk Control panel on my remote server (port 8443).

Im fairly adept at web programming and can think of a few ways of exposing the table for a remote admin interface that would run on port 80 with a little login screen, it seems like a lot of work to get around a port blocking though, considering as well that I will only use it a few times.

I could also install another instance of phpMyAdmin somewhere else on the server and use that, but then I feel like Im exposing a whole bunch of security issues, once again just to overcome a specific clients' port blocking.

Im pretty sure I can't change the existing phpMyAdmin port number, as it must be accessed through Plesk.

All this being said, Im hoping that someone can recommend an easy solution that will help in this situation. Maybe an out of the box element that allows me to edit a single table and I can just start a session if my correct password is posted to the page?

Im looking for any specific answer just an general idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the remote host (where Plesk and phpMyAdmin are installed)? If so, you could make an SSH tunnel with the command `ssh user@host.tld -L 80:127.0.0.1:8443` and then access Plesk via `http://localhost/`.

Comment: Is your web server Apache (and are you able to modify its configuration)?

Comment: @Carsten Ive never seen bind address used with ssh, do you mean that if I log in with this address and X Forwarding I could run a browser on the remote server, and access the page through port 80?  The difficulty with that is that Im not sure I can easily install X and a web server on my remote host.

Comment: @YaK Yes it is and I do, from what I can see I don't have control over the Plesk (MediaTemple) interface that I am currently accessing phpMyAdmin through

Comment: @Carsten Thank you so much that is perfect! I understand what you mean now.  If you would like to post this as an answer Ill happily accept it

Comment: Okay, posting it as an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the remote host (where Plesk and phpMyAdmin are installed), you can make an SSH tunnel with the command `ssh user@host.tld -L 80:127.0.0.1:8443` and then access Plesk via `http://localhost/`.

If there's already a webserver present on your local host, change the port `80` in the SSH command accordingly.

Also, you should consult SSH's man page. SSH tunneling offers great possibilities (you could just bind an admin console to 127.0.0.1 and still access it from your own computer, using an SSH tunnel).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Apache so that it [listens to several ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).

This does not create another potential security hole. In fact, it merely exposes on port 80 the same potential security holes as the ones already exposed on port 8443. With the exception that port 80 is a well-known port, more prone to scanning.

You could (should?) also configure Apache so that it allows connections [only from a small set of IP](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

You could add something like this in your Apache configuration:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory /path/to/phpMyAdmin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From [space-separated list of authorised IP here]
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/phpMyAdmin
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm checking to see with my web host if I can access the '/path/to/phpMyAdmin' directly

Comment: @jimmyjambles Carsten's solution is much more elegant, I now realise it too.